# mongoDB not inserting value using angular factory to do post method

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

how come its sending data to mongo if I $http.post directly in the controller?

```
$http.post('/api/users/', vm.newUser).success(function(response){
```

But using the code below doesn't seems to work, it's not passing any value but generates ID in mongoDB

```
vm.signupNewUser = function () {
        signupService.signupNewUser(vm.newUser).success(function(response){ 
                console.log(vm.newUser);
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

service:

```
function _signupNewUser(username, password, email, fname, lname){
        var data = {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            email: email,
            fname: fname,
            lname: lname
        }
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/users',
            data: data
        })
    }
```

Edit: this seems to fix it, but not sure how is it different from using a direct $http.post and just passing vm.newUser. But using factory I have to pass in vm.newUser.username and etc. I don't think passing the vm like this is ideal but please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
vm.signupNewUser = function () {
        signupService.signupNewUser(vm.newUser.username, vm.newUser.password, vm.newUser.email, vm.newUser.fname, vm.newUser.lname)
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                console.log(vm.newUser);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Wait.. you're making direct calls to a mongo collection.. from a front end app?? Why???

Comment: No, front-end is creating the collection to mongo, only created the database. Using angular factory to do post method doesn't seems to work but it generates ID in the collection "user"

Comment: can you post your factory code? it should not matter if you use a factory or controller.  unless you are trying to return the $http request from the factory to the controller

Comment: I've edited my original post, my factory is the _signupNewUser and calling it on vm.signupNewUser in the controller. I agree it shouldn't matter but for some reason my factory doesn't seems to send the data to my db. Unless I'm calling it wrong.

Comment: Added a fix but please answer the question in the edit part.

Comment: Can you put together the codes in a Jsfiddle?